# Pandas turn column with list into string

Tags: python, pandas

I have a column in my dataframe that holds locations.

some of the locations are written down like this:  `['Vinkovci', 'Croatia']` and some written like so: `Vinkovci,Coratia`. I want them all to be written like the second approach.

Comment: `df['column']=df['column'].astype(str).str.strip('[]').str.replace("'",'')`?

Comment: @Anurag Dabas Thanks!

Comment: If the data is in a list format to start (and not str), then this should work as well. `df['column'].map(','.join)`